# Worksheet_Activate does not run when opening workbook, even if I call sheet.Activate

Tags: excel, vba

Currently I have created VBA code in worksheet 1 "Sheet1" as

```
  Private Sub Worksheet_Activate ()
```

So every time I open the worksheet the VBA code will auto run.

But the problem I'm facing now is every time I open the Excel workbook, even though I added the codding in ThisWorkbook,

```
 Private Sub Workbook_Open()

     Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

 End Sub
```

the worksheet will appear first but the VBA code won't auto run. Every time I need to shift another worksheet then shift back again, then only the VBA code will run, this is very annoying, is there any solution to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the [Worksheet.Activate method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838003.aspx) won't do anything if that worksheet was already active.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Make sure that you are passing the activation trigger to another worksheet and back to Sheet1 in order to run the Worksheet_Activate event macro or just run the code from the Workbook_Open sub.

Answer (score 2):

Make the `Worksheet_Activate` `Public` instead of `Private`, then run `Worksheet("???").Worksheet_Activate` within you `Workbook_Open` code.

Comment: It works!  and I think that this answer should be accepted as the best one